# Are there any other sources for Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: release-management

I am now using ubuntu 11.10 but I would like to download ubuntu 9.10 for testing purposes (Compiz experimental plugins). My bandwith is very slow, so I am using a download manager that will support downloading files from multiple sources (Downthemall Firefox extension). The problem is, I can only find one source for this file, which is on the main Ubuntu server. Are there any other sources for this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of [Ubuntu mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)...choose at your leisure.

But not all versions are hosted at all mirror, you might have difficulty in finding older versions...

Answer (score 6):

In this site: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ you will find below several options to download including (If you want to download from multiple sources) torrent format.

After doing some searching I found several FTP and HTTP sites that had all releases from 8.04 and above EXCEPT the 9.04 and 9.10. The only ones I found were:

http://nginyang.uvt.nl/karmic/ (DVD Release)

http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-dvd-releases/releases/9.10/release/ (DVD Release)

Also a list of mirrors (Most of which do not have the 9.10 to download directly. Some of them have the torrent format for it): https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors